# Computing the overtimepay is my formula correct?

Tags: c, algorithm

An  employee is paid at a rate of 9.73 per hour for up to 40 hours worked per week. Any hours over that are paid at the over time rate of 1 and 1/2 times that.

My algorithm for this statement "Any hours over that are paid at the over time rate of 1.5 times that." is the one which confuses me.

Here is the code:

```
double hours, overtimepay, overtimehours, wage;
printf("Enter number of hours: ")
scanf("%f",&hours);

wage=9.73*hours;
overtimehours=hours-40;
overtimepay=(9.73*overtimehours)*1.5);

if(hours>40){
printf("Your wage is: %f",wage);
printf("Your overtime pay is: %f",overtimepay);
}

else{
printf("Your wage is: %f",wage);
}
```

I'm confused on how will I calculate the overtime pay or rate. 1 and 1/2 is equivalent to 1.5 (if I am not mistaken). So here's my formula:

```
overtimepay=(9.73*overtimehours)*1.5);
```

Because my overtimehours is from subtracting hours from the 40 hours where for example if I type in 43 hours, 43-40=3 so there's an overtime hours of 3 hours. The three hours will be multiplied with the 9.73 and 1.5. Is it right to multiply 9.73, overtimehours, and 1.5 together? Or is it just overtimehours and 1.5?

Comment: Why are you asking us if it's correct or not? Did you run and test yourself? PS: Looks correct to me, the only thing I'd change is to add the `overtimehours` and `overtimepay` to the `if(hours>40)` block, since if hours is less than 40, there's no point in calculating overtimepay.

Comment: You are double counting the overtime hours. `wage` shouldn't include 9.73 for the overtime hours.

Comment: its correct..what's the problem??you should write `overtimepay=(9.73*overtimehours)*1.5;` if its not typo..

also `wage += overtimepay`

Comment: Change the hourly rate to something simple, like 1 or 10. Do a few cases using pen and paper. Then compare to your program's result. Also compare your pen-and-paper calculations to your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is alright (not that complicated after all!), I'd just suggest to change your condition statement to reduce a bit your code:

```
double hours, overtimepay, wage;
printf("Enter number of hours: ")
scanf("%f",&hours);

wage=9.73*hours;
wage = 9.73 * hours;

printf("Your wage is: %f\n",wage);

if(hours > 40)
{
   overtimepay = (9.73*(hours-40))*1.5;
   printf("Your overtime pay is: %f\n", overtimepay);
}
```